# How can I update models on database change using Database first approach?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have created models from Entity Framework Core 5 using database first approach. I have made some changes in database now.

Is there any way to update models other than Force approach which will overwrite all models?

Answer (score 0):

I usually find it easier to manually update the affected model classes.